# Can an app tell if it's been downloaded through an unofficial store?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, alternative-markets

Let's say I download an app using Aurora Store and I start using it, can this app know what source it has been downloaded from?
Can it tell if the download source was different from the Play Store?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/70421457

Answer (score 2):

Android saves for each app by which other app the app had been installed. This information can be queried via [Android API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70421457) and it can be queried using `pm` on adb level:

First list the packages installed:

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

Select an app package name from the list you want to query, e.g. Chrome `com.android.chrome`, and execute:

```
adb shell pm dump com.android.chrome | grep installerPackageName
```

Usually you will get the result that it had been installed from Google Play Store:

```
installerPackageName=com.android.vending
```

Other possible values (observed on Android 13) are `com.google.android.packageinstaller` if the app had been e.g. downloaded by a third party app (e.g. Chrome, Firefox F-Droid) and directly installed.

Apps installed via Aurora Store Session Installer will end up with

```
installerPackageName=com.aurora.store
```

Apps that have been installed via `adb install` don't have the `installerPackageName` property.

Also of interest could be the `packageSource` value on Android 13+ devices.

```
adb shell pm dump com.android.chrome | grep packageSource
```

These are the possible `packageSource` values.

- 0 = [PACKAGE_SOURCE_STORE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller#PACKAGE_SOURCE_STORE) - Play Store, also for apps installed via adb
- 1 = [PACKAGE_SOURCE_OTHER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller#PACKAGE_SOURCE_OTHER)
- 2 = ??
- 3 = [PACKAGE_SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller#PACKAGE_SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE) - web browser, third party store
- 4 = [PACKAGE_SOURCE_DOWNLOADED_FILE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller#PACKAGE_SOURCE_DOWNLOADED_FILE)